# address(this) in solidity is returning wrong contract address

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript, ganache, truffle-test

This is my cantract code which I was using in truffle

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;

contract Test {
    function getAdd() public view returns(address){
        address add = address(this);
        return add;
    }
}
```

This is my js Test code

```
const Test = artifacts.require('../contracts/Test.sol');

contract('Test',(accounts)=>{

    it('Testing Testing',async()=>{
        let ins =await Test.deployed();
        let ans =await ins.getAdd.call();
        console.log(ans)
    })
})
```

and I am using ganache for my local blockchain

when I run truffle test command it gives me the result 
0x4cB6949669C8631fb2f99Bbe890B99B7DbF64685

but in ganache contract section the deployed contract address is
0xc48Cda939749b1Da32E6853184D595a30c5accCf

I don't know what is going wrong here as address(this) should have return my contract address but it is not working as expected

Steps I have done are:-

1. truffle init
2. wrote the contract
3. wrote migration file

   const Test = artifacts.require("Test");

   module.exports = function(deployer) {
   deployer.deploy(Test); 
   };

`truffle compile` 
5. truffle migrate 
6. truffle test

I dont know why I am getting wrong address in that but when i tried it on remix it was working please help!!

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need `await ins.getAdd.call()`, you can simply use `ins.address`.

Comment: but why address (this) is not working.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you

```
console.log(ins.address, ans);
```

... you will find they are the same.

If so, the issue is confusion about the instance of the contract that `deployed()` is using. It is the most recent, on this network, *that the deployer knows about*, but not necessarily what you expect. It gets updated with each `deployer.deploy()`.

Hope it helps.